# Wy Lightsail AvailabilityZones not working?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-lightsail

I try to get zones from lightsail, but I see regions with empty values.

```
>>> ls = boto3.client('lightsail')
>>> ls.get_regions(includeAvailabilityZones=True)
{u'regions': [{u'displayName': u'Virginia', u'description': u'This region is recommended to serve users in the eastern United States', u'relationalDatabaseAvailabilityZones': [], u'availabilityZones': []...
```

Why? Only one Asia regions with

```
{u'state': u'available', u'zoneName': u'ap-south-1b'}], u'continentCode': u'AP', u'name': u'ap-south-1'}
```

Comment: Is this a new account?  What do you find if you use the Lightsail web console to discover the same information (using the same AWS account, of course)?  Are the regions and AZs visible to you, there?

Comment: yes, regions is visible from account.

Comment: The availability zones are populated for the region you're calling. It looks like you configured boto (or AWS CLI) for `ap-south-1` -- which is why you only see the AZs there. If you change that, you'll see AZs for the region you end up calling.